# opencv jni build failed by using ndk (error: undefined reference)

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

```
OpenCV version = 3.1.0
Dlib version = 19.1
Android NDK version = r21
```

I would like to build lib.so file for Android Studio by using Android NDK. However, it failed in the SharedLibrary and OpenCV involved in all errors. I checked my directory path and it does not have any mistake. Can anyone tell help me?

This is the tutorial that I followed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZjZHiPWBiYY&t=2192s

**Application.mk:**

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a x86 x86_64
APP_CPPFLAGS := -std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions
APP_PLATFORM := android-16
APP_STL := c++_static
```

**Android.mk:**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_MODULE := dlib 
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/dlib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += \
            ../$(LOCAL_PATH)/dlib//dlib/threads/threads_kernel_shared.cpp \
            ../$(LOCAL_PATH)/dlib/dlib/entropy_decoder/entropy_decoder_kernel_2.cpp \
            ../$(LOCAL_PATH)/dlib/dlib/base64/base64_kernel_1.cpp \
            ../$(LOCAL_PATH)/dlib/dlib/threads/threads_kernel_1.cpp \
            ../$(LOCAL_PATH)/dlib/dlib/threads/threads_kernel_2.cpp  
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_C_INCLUDES)
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)


TOP_LEVEL_PATH := $(abspath $(LOCAL_PATH)/..)
$(info TOP Level Path: $(TOP_LEVEL_PATH))
EXT_INSTALL_PATH = $(TOP_LEVEL_PATH)/third_party
OPENCV_PATH = $(EXT_INSTALL_PATH)/opencv/jni
OPENCV_INCLUDE_DIR = $(OPENCV_PATH)/include
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
OpenCV_INSTALL_MODULES := on
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES := off
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE := STATIC
include $(OPENCV_PATH)/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE := MyLibs
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += \
     $(OPENCV_INCLUDE_DIR)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_example_opencvdlib_NativeClass.cpp

LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lm -llog -ldl -lz -ljnigraphics
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions -frtti -std=c++11

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += dlib

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**Errors:**

```
C:\Users\leech\Desktop\AndroidApp\generateLibs>ndk-build

TOP Level Path: C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs

TOP Level Path: C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs

TOP Level Path: C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs

TOP Level Path: C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs

[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: MyLibs <= com_example_opencvdlib_NativeClass.cpp

jni/com_example_opencvdlib_NativeClass.cpp:6:2: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
        }
        ^
1 warning generated.

[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: dlib <= threads_kernel_shared.cpp

[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: dlib <= entropy_decoder_kernel_2.cpp

[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: dlib <= base64_kernel_1.cpp

[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: dlib <= threads_kernel_1.cpp

[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: dlib <= threads_kernel_2.cpp

[armeabi-v7a] StaticLibrary  : libdlib.a

[armeabi-v7a] SharedLibrary  : libMyLibs.so

C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_imgproc.a(drawing.cpp.o):drawing.cpp:function std::vector<cv::PolyEdge, std::allocator<cv::PolyEdge> >::reserve(unsigned int): error: undefined reference to 'std::__throw_length_error(char const*)'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_imgproc.a(drawing.cpp.o):drawing.cpp:function std::vector<cv::Point_<int>, std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > >::_M_fill_insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<cv::Point_<int>*, std::vector<cv::Point_<int>, std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > >, unsigned int, cv::Point_<int> const&): error: undefined reference to 'std::__throw_length_error(char const*)'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_imgproc.a(drawing.cpp.o):drawing.cpp:function std::vector<CvSeq, std::allocator<CvSeq> >::_M_fill_insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<CvSeq*, std::vector<CvSeq, std::allocator<CvSeq> > >, unsigned int, CvSeq const&): error: undefined reference to 'std::__throw_length_error(char const*)'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_imgproc.a(drawing.cpp.o):drawing.cpp:function std::vector<CvSeqBlock, std::allocator<CvSeqBlock> >::_M_fill_insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<CvSeqBlock*, std::vector<CvSeqBlock, std::allocator<CvSeqBlock> > >, unsigned int, CvSeqBlock const&): error: undefined reference to 'std::__throw_length_error(char const*)'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(system.cpp.o):system.cpp:function _GLOBAL__sub_I_system.cpp: error: undefined reference to 'std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(system.cpp.o):system.cpp:function _GLOBAL__sub_I_system.cpp: error: undefined reference to 'std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) [clone .part.39]: error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::clear(std::_Ios_Iostate)'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function std::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringbuf(): error: undefined reference to 'vtable for std::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
C:/android-ndk-r21/build//../toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function std::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringbuf(): error: undefined reference to 'vtable for std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >'
C:/android-ndk-r21/build//../toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function std::string cv::ocl::kerToStr<float>(cv::Mat const&): error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::str() const'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function std::string cv::ocl::kerToStr<float>(cv::Mat const&): error: undefined reference to 'vtable for std::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
C:/android-ndk-r21/build//../toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function std::string cv::ocl::kerToStr<float>(cv::Mat const&): error: undefined reference to 'vtable for std::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
C:/android-ndk-r21/build//../toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function std::string cv::ocl::kerToStr<float>(cv::Mat const&): error: undefined reference to 'std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function std::string cv::ocl::kerToStr<float>(cv::Mat const&): error: undefined reference to 'vtable for std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >'
C:/android-ndk-r21/build//../toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function std::string cv::ocl::kerToStr<float>(cv::Mat const&): error: undefined reference to 'VTT for std::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function std::string cv::ocl::kerToStr<float>(cv::Mat const&): error: undefined reference to 'vtable for std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >'
C:/android-ndk-r21/build//../toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function std::string cv::ocl::kerToStr<double>(cv::Mat const&): error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_ostringstream(std::_Ios_Openmode)'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function std::string cv::ocl::kerToStr<double>(cv::Mat const&): error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::str() const'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function std::string cv::ocl::kerToStr<double>(cv::Mat const&): error: undefined reference to 'vtable for std::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
C:/android-ndk-r21/build//../toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function std::string cv::ocl::kerToStr<double>(cv::Mat const&): error: undefined reference to 'vtable for std::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function std::string cv::ocl::kerToStr<double>(cv::Mat const&): error: undefined reference to 'vtable for std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >'
C:/android-ndk-r21/build//../toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function std::string cv::ocl::kerToStr<unsigned short>(cv::Mat const&): error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_ostringstream()'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function std::string cv::ocl::kerToStr<unsigned short>(cv::Mat const&): error: undefined reference to 'vtable for std::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
C:/android-ndk-r21/build//../toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function std::string cv::ocl::kerToStr<unsigned short>(cv::Mat const&): error: undefined reference to 'VTT for std::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function std::string cv::ocl::kerToStr<unsigned short>(cv::Mat const&): error: undefined reference to 'vtable for std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >'
C:/android-ndk-r21/build//../toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function std::string cv::ocl::kerToStr<short>(cv::Mat const&): error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_ostringstream(std::_Ios_Openmode)'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function std::string cv::ocl::kerToStr<short>(cv::Mat const&): error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::str() const'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function std::string cv::ocl::kerToStr<short>(cv::Mat const&): error: undefined reference to 'std::ios_base::~ios_base()'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function std::string cv::ocl::kerToStr<short>(cv::Mat const&): error: undefined reference to 'std::ostream::operator<<(short)'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function std::string cv::ocl::kerToStr<short>(cv::Mat const&): error: undefined reference to 'vtable for std::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
C:/android-ndk-r21/build//../toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function std::string cv::ocl::kerToStr<short>(cv::Mat const&): error: undefined reference to 'VTT for std::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function std::string cv::ocl::kerToStr<short>(cv::Mat const&): error: undefined reference to 'vtable for std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >'
C:/android-ndk-r21/build//../toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function cv::ocl::OpenCLBufferPoolBaseImpl<cv::ocl::OpenCLBufferPoolImpl, cv::ocl::CLBufferEntry, _cl_mem*>::setMaxReservedSize(unsigned int): error: undefined reference to 'std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_unhook()'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function cv::ocl::OpenCLBufferPoolBaseImpl<cv::ocl::OpenCLBufferPoolImpl, cv::ocl::CLBufferEntry, _cl_mem*>::setMaxReservedSize(unsigned int): error: undefined reference to 'std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_unhook()'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function cv::ocl::OpenCLBufferPoolBaseImpl<cv::ocl::OpenCLBufferPoolImpl, cv::ocl::CLBufferEntry, _cl_mem*>::release(_cl_mem*): error: undefined reference to 'std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_unhook()'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function cv::ocl::OpenCLBufferPoolBaseImpl<cv::ocl::OpenCLBufferPoolImpl, cv::ocl::CLBufferEntry, _cl_mem*>::release(_cl_mem*): error: undefined reference to 'std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_hook(std::__detail::_List_node_base*)'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function cv::ocl::OpenCLBufferPoolBaseImpl<cv::ocl::OpenCLBufferPoolImpl, cv::ocl::CLBufferEntry, _cl_mem*>::release(_cl_mem*): error: undefined reference to 'std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_unhook()'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function cv::ocl::kernelToStr(cv::_InputArray const&, int, char const*): error: undefined reference to 'std::string::_Rep::_M_dispose(std::allocator<char> const&)'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function cv::ocl::Kernel::set(int, cv::ocl::Image2D const&): error: undefined reference to 'std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_hook(std::__detail::_List_node_base*)'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::string*, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > >, std::string const&): error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&)'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::string*, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > >, std::string const&): error: undefined reference to 'std::string::_Rep::_M_dispose(std::allocator<char> const&)'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::string*, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > >, std::string const&): error: undefined reference to 'std::string::_Rep::_M_dispose(std::allocator<char> const&)'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::string*, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > >, std::string const&): error: undefined reference to 'std::string::_Rep::_M_dispose(std::allocator<char> const&)'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function cv::ocl::split(std::string const&, char, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >&): error: undefined reference to 'std::ios_base::ios_base()'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function cv::ocl::split(std::string const&, char, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >&): error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::init(std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >*)'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function cv::ocl::split(std::string const&, char, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >&): error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_sync(char*, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function cv::ocl::split(std::string const&, char, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >&): error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::init(std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >*)'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function cv::ocl::split(std::string const&, char, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >&): error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::getline<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, char)'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function cv::ocl::split(std::string const&, char, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >&): error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_istringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_istringstream()'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function cv::ocl::split(std::string const&, char, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >&): error: undefined reference to 'VTT for std::basic_istringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function cv::ocl::split(std::string const&, char, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >&): error: undefined reference to 'vtable for std::basic_istringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
C:/android-ndk-r21/build//../toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function std::_Rb_tree<cv::ocl::Context::Impl::HashKey, std::pair<cv::ocl::Context::Impl::HashKey const, cv::ocl::Program>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<cv::ocl::Context::Impl::HashKey const, cv::ocl::Program> >, std::less<cv::ocl::Context::Impl::HashKey>, std::allocator<std::pair<cv::ocl::Context::Impl::HashKey const, cv::ocl::Program> > >::_M_insert_unique(std::pair<cv::ocl::Context::Impl::HashKey const, cv::ocl::Program> const&): error: undefined reference to 'std::_Rb_tree_decrement(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*)'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function std::_Rb_tree<cv::ocl::Context::Impl::HashKey, std::pair<cv::ocl::Context::Impl::HashKey const, cv::ocl::Program>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<cv::ocl::Context::Impl::HashKey const, cv::ocl::Program> >, std::less<cv::ocl::Context::Impl::HashKey>, std::allocator<std::pair<cv::ocl::Context::Impl::HashKey const, cv::ocl::Program> > >::_M_insert_unique(std::pair<cv::ocl::Context::Impl::HashKey const, cv::ocl::Program> const&): error: undefined reference to 'std::_Rb_tree_insert_and_rebalance(bool, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base&)'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function int cv::ocl::getStringInfo<int (*)(_cl_platform_id*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*, unsigned int*), _cl_platform_id*>(int (*)(_cl_platform_id*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*, unsigned int*), _cl_platform_id*, unsigned int, std::string&) [clone .constprop.272]: error: undefined reference to 'std::string::_M_mutate(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function int cv::ocl::getStringInfo<int (*)(_cl_platform_id*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*, unsigned int*), _cl_platform_id*>(int (*)(_cl_platform_id*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*, unsigned int*), _cl_platform_id*, unsigned int, std::string&) [clone .constprop.272]: error: undefined reference to 'std::string::assign(char const*, unsigned int)'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function cv::ocl::OpenCLBufferPoolBaseImpl<cv::ocl::OpenCLBufferPoolImpl, cv::ocl::CLBufferEntry, _cl_mem*>::_findAndRemoveEntryFromReservedList(cv::ocl::CLBufferEntry&, unsigned int): error: undefined reference to 'std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_hook(std::__detail::_List_node_base*)'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function cv::ocl::Context::Impl::setDefault(): error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function cv::ocl::Context::Impl::setDefault(): error: undefined reference to 'std::string::find(char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int) const'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function cv::ocl::OpenCLBufferPoolImpl::_allocateBufferEntry(cv::ocl::CLBufferEntry&, unsigned int): error: undefined reference to 'std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_hook(std::__detail::_List_node_base*)'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function _GLOBAL__sub_I_ocl.cpp: error: undefined reference to 'std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.a(ocl.cpp.o):ocl.cpp:function _GLOBAL__sub_I_ocl.cpp: error: undefined reference to 'std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../3rdparty/libs/armeabi-v7a/libtbb.a(tbb_misc.cpp.o):tbb_misc.cpp:function tbb::internal::handle_perror(int, char const*): error: undefined reference to 'std::runtime_error::runtime_error(std::string const&)'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../3rdparty/libs/armeabi-v7a/libtbb.a(tbb_misc.cpp.o):tbb_misc.cpp:function tbb::internal::throw_exception_v4(tbb::internal::exception_id): error: undefined reference to 'std::runtime_error::runtime_error(std::string const&)'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../3rdparty/libs/armeabi-v7a/libtbb.a(tbb_misc.cpp.o):tbb_misc.cpp:function tbb::internal::throw_exception_v4(tbb::internal::exception_id): error: undefined reference to 'std::runtime_error::runtime_error(std::string const&)'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../3rdparty/libs/armeabi-v7a/libtbb.a(tbb_misc.cpp.o):tbb_misc.cpp:function tbb::internal::throw_exception_v4(tbb::internal::exception_id): error: undefined reference to 'std::runtime_error::runtime_error(std::string const&)'
C:/Users/leech/Desktop/AndroidApp/generateLibs/third_party/opencv/jni/../3rdparty/libs/armeabi-v7a/libtbb.a(tbb_misc.cpp.o):tbb_misc.cpp:function tbb::internal::throw_exception_v4(tbb::internal::exception_id): error: undefined reference to 'std::invalid_argument::invalid_argument(std::string const&)'
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [C:/android-ndk-r21/build//../build/core/build-binary.mk:725: obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libMyLibs.so] Error 1
```

Can anyone tell me what have I did wrong?

Comment: For people who do not have the time to watch an entire YouTube video, could you edit your question to show _how_ you compiled openCV? A quick Google search tells me this can be caused by not using the same compiler or using a different flavor of STL for both components.